# How to verify that multipart zip file is valid

Tags: linux, zip

I want to verify that a multipart zip file that I've created is valid, but because of the 4 GB output limit imposed by my filesystem, I am unable to do so.

I used the following command to create a multipart zip file:

```
zip -9 -r -s 3g MyArchive.zip MyDirectory
```

I then attempted to verify that the resulting zip file is valid with the following commands:

```
cat MyArchive.z01 MyArchive.zip > Output.zip
unzip Output.zip
```

But the unzip command is giving me the following error message

```
zip I/O error: File too large
```

How can I verify that the multipart zip file is valid?

Comment: Why are you manually concatenating the parts? That's not how multi-part archives work.

Comment: What should I be doing instead?

Comment: Which OS are you on?

Comment: I'm on Linux Mint

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use for example `7z`

```
7z t MyArchive.zip
```

waiting for a message as `Everything is Ok`.

With `unzip` you may try `unzip -t Output.zip`.
It throws me some warning and errors but at the end

> Archive:  a.zip
> **warning** [a.zip]:  zipfile claims to be last disk of a multi-part archive;
> attempting to process anyway, assuming all parts have been concatenated
> together in order.  **Expect "errors" and warnings...true multi-part support doesn't exist yet (coming soon).**
> **warning** [a.zip]:  629145600 extra bytes at beginning or within zipfile
> (attempting to process anyway)
> file #1:  bad zipfile offset (local header sig):  629145604
> (attempting to re-compensate)

> testing: nomefile....  OK

Notes:

- `unzip` UnZip 6.00 of 20 April 2009, by Debian. Original by Info-ZIP.
- `7-Zip` [64] 16.02 (maybe via `p7zip` wrapper).